# preg_replace when not inside double quotes

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Basically I want to replace certain words (e.g. the word "tree" with the word "pizza") in sentences. Restriction: When the word that should be replaced is between double quotes, the replace should not be performed.

Example:

```
The tree is green. -> REPLACE tree WITH pizza
"The" tree is "green". -> REPLACE tree WITH pizza
"The tree" is green. -> DONT REPLACE
"The tree is" green. -> DONT REPLACE
The ""tree is green. -> REPLACE tree WITH pizza
```

Is it possible to do this with regular expressions? I would count the number of double quotes before the word and check if it is odd or even. But is this possible using preg_replace in php?

Thanks!

//EDIT:

At the moment my code looks like the following:

```
preg_replace("/tree/", "pizza", $sentence)
```

But the problem here is to implement the logic with the double quotes. I tried things like:

```
preg_replace("/[^"]tree/", "pizza", $sentence)
```

But this does not work, because it checks only if a double quote is in front of the word. But there are examples above where this check fails.
Import is that I want to solve that problem with regex only.

Comment: This is tagged as php, but you ave shown nothing to support that it is php, can you please show the code that you have tried and show the string you are trying to preg-replace in php. We are not here to code for you, so help us out.

Answer (score 9):

Regular expression is not a tool that will do what you need for every job. You can use regular expression for this to a certain extent, but for all cases amongst **nested quotes**, it continues to get more complicated.

You could use a **Negative Lookahead** here.

```
$text = preg_replace('/\btree\b(?![^"]*"(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)/i', 'pizza', $text);
```

See [`Working demo`](https://eval.in/82653)

Regular expression:

```
\b               the boundary between a word char (\w) and not a word char
 tree            'tree'
\b               the boundary between a word char (\w) and not a word char
(?!              look ahead to see if there is not:
 [^"]*           any character except: '"' (0 or more times)
  "              '"'
 (?:             group, but do not capture (0 or more times)
  (?:            group, but do not capture (2 times):
   [^"]*         any character except: '"' (0 or more times)
    "            '"'
  ){2}           end of grouping
 )*              end of grouping
 [^"]*           any character except: '"' (0 or more times)
 $               before an optional \n, and the end of the string
)                end of look-ahead
```

Another option is to use controlled backtracking since your able to do this in [php](/questions/tagged/php)

```
$text = preg_replace('/"[^"]*"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\btree\b/i', 'pizza', $text);
```

See [`Working demo`](https://eval.in/82654)

The idea is to skip content in quotations. I first match the quotation followed by any character except `"` followed by a quotation and then make the subpattern fail and force the regular expression engine to not retry the substring with an other alternative with `(*SKIP)` and `(*FAIL)` backtracking control verbs.

Comment: This does look amazing and works as I expected. Could you explain this to me? I see that it looks for the word "tree" not followed by this huge statement. But what does it exactly?

Comment: All the answers here don't work for string with Chinese characters.

Comment: I've just tried this in phpstorm/php7 and get a "Dangling metacharacter" error against the *SKIP and *FAIL asterisks. Has preg_replace changed since 2013?

Answer (score 6):

There is a handy trick using some hidden regex powers :

`~".*?"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\btree\b~s`

**Explanation:**

```
~                   # start delimiter (we could have used /, #, @ etc...)
"                   # match a double quote
.*?                 # match anything ungreedy until ...
"                   # match a double quote
(*SKIP)(*FAIL)      # make it fail
|                   # or
\btree\b            # match a tree with wordboundaries
~                   # end delimiter
s                   # setting the s modifier to match newlines with dots .
```

In actual PHP code, you would want to use [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/preg_quote) to escape regex characters. Here's a little snippet:

```
$search = 'tree';
$replace = 'plant';
$input = 'The tree is green.
"The" tree is "green".
"The tree" is green.
"The tree is" green.
The ""tree is green.';

$regex = '~".*?"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\b' . preg_quote($search, '~') . '\b~s';
$output = preg_replace($regex, $replace, $input);
echo $output;
```

<kbd>[**Online regex demo**](http://regex101.com/r/sM7hX5)</kbd>     <kbd>[**Online PHP demo**](https://eval.in/82650)</kbd>

Comment: Hey that's great! Where can I read more about those hidden powers?

Comment: @Jonny5 The PHP manual doesn't describe all the capabilities of the PCRE library. So you're better off reading the [pcre manual](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt). Of course it's too long. I basically learned these things by hanging around Stackoverflow ... Ah and reading the perl manual might also be a good idea. [See this link](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Special-Backtracking-Control-Verbs).

Comment: How does it work? Why wouldn't it replace `tree` in `That's "some tree you" have there.`?

Comment: The `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` isn't the secret, is it? It could be anything, like `(*FOO)(*BAR)`?

Comment: @Rudie I've explained it, well I guess it wasn't clear enough ... Anyways, `".*?"` will match anything that's between double quotes even "tree". I've added `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` to make it skip/fail that match. After that, I've added an alternation `|\btree\b` to match the actual tree

Comment: @Rudie `(*SKIP)` and `(*FAIL)` are regex control verbs, that's why I said "hidden powers" since they are not used that much in the wild. You might read this [section](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Special-Backtracking-Control-Verbs) of the perl docs.

Comment: I'm reading the PCRE link now. Wow, those verbs are super super useful! How are they not advertised!? This regex rocks!

Comment: Well they aren't because most people have a headache for several days by just taking a look at simple regexes. That said, I've got to put a list of "interesting regex Q/A on StackOverflow" ...

Comment: See http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c3c9a68a4bf82f3421aeddc7706b8d656fbd301e for a working demo of this, but running with single quotes instead of double

Answer (score 1):

This one matches `tree` using a lookahead:

```
$pattern = '~\btree\b(?=([^"]|("[^"]*"))*$)~im';

$str = '
The tree is green. -> REPLACE tree WITH pizza
"The" tree is "green". -> REPLACE tree WITH pizza
"The tree" is green. -> DONT REPLACE
"The tree is" green. -> DONT REPLACE
The ""tree is green. -> REPLACE tree WITH pizza';

echo "<pre>".preg_replace($pattern,"pizza",$str)."</pre>";
```

It looks for `tree`, if found, matches it only, if followed by characters, that are not double-quotes `[^"]` or quoted groups `"[^"]*"` until end of line using [modifiers i (PCRE_CASELESS) and m (PCRE_MULTILINE)](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

I don't want a green pizza! Merry Xmas :-)

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern `tree(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)` with `gm` options [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/zS5kK4)

this is how it is constructed from the ground up:
`tree(?=[^"]*")`  "tree" that sees any amount of non-quote characters followed by a quote
`tree(?=([^"]*"){2})`  ~ twice
`tree(?=(([^"]*"){2})*)`  ~ as many times as possible
`tree(?=(([^"]*"){2})*[^"]*)`  ~ then optional non-quote characters
`tree(?=(([^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)`  ~ to the end
`tree(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)`   add non-capturing groups

[php demo](https://eval.in/82662)

Comment: Like I said on the other answer. This is amazing and works really nice. Could you explain the part behind the word tree? It looks really difficult.

Comment: PHP doesn't support the g option. (granted in my opinion it should since preg is supposed to stand for perl reg ex)

Comment: @Zarazthuztra I don't know PHP but I do know the attached Demo works and the OP confirmed it.

Comment: Which is awesome, except that the Demo site is doing that with JS, not PHP, regardless of the "flavor" you set (I actually just learned this recently myself):
http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: @Zarazthuztra PHP doesn't have the `g` modifier. To match a single instance you could use `preg_match()`, to match all you just need to use a different function `preg_match_all()`. Replacing `preg_replace()` is by default replacing all occurences. We could limit it though using the fourth parameter.

Comment: @HamZa Yes, I already know all that. Was trying to help with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm building a JS minimizer and this page helped me a lot with getting to the right regular expressions for it. But what this page has not answered sofar is what to do when a quoted string contains escaped quotes. I bookmarked this page for when I found the recipe.

```
/*
Regular expression group 'NotBetween'.
*/
function rgxgNotBetween($chars, $sep="|")
{
    $chars = explode($sep, $chars);

    $NB = [];

    foreach($chars as $CHR){
        //(*PRUNE) steps over $CHR when it is escaped; that is, preceded by a backslash.
        $NB[] = "(?:$CHR(?:\\\\$CHR(*PRUNE)|.)*?$CHR)";
    }

    $NB = join("|", $NB);

    return "(?:(?:$NB)(*SKIP)(*FAIL))";
}

function jsIdReplace($search, $replace, $source)
{
    $search = ""

    //SKIP further matching when between...
    //double or single qoutes or js regular expression slashes
    .rgxgNotBetween("\x22|\x27|\/")

    //match when NO preceding '.' and no ending ':' (object properties)
    ."|(?:(?<!\.)\b$search\b(?!:))"

    //but do match when preceding '?' or ':' AND ending ':' (ternary statements)
    ."|(?:(?<=\?|:)\b$search\b(?=:))";

    return preg_replace($search, $replace, $source);
}

function jsNoComments($source)
{
    //js comment markers NOT between quotes
    $NBQ = rgxgNotBetween("\x22|\x27");

    //block comments
    $source = preg_replace("#$NBQ|/\*.*?\*/#s", "", $source);

    //line comments; not preceded by backslash
    $source = preg_replace("#$NBQ|\h*(?<!\\\\)//.*\n?#", "", $source);

    return $source;
}
```