# SKIP-FAIL regex with multiple patterns to ignore in one PCRE regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to replace one string with another but only if it's out of double or single quotes.
I can do it for doubles, but I have problems to include singles as well.

I use preg_repalce with array because I also have other rules to apply to the string.

```
$text = <<<DATA
I love php
"I love php"
'I love php'
"I" love 'php'
DATA;

$text = preg_replace(
    [
     '/"[^"]*"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\blove\b/i'
    ],
    [
     'hate'
    ],
    $text
);

echo $text;
```

and the output is

```
I hate php     -> OK
"I love php"   -> OK
'I hate php'   -> NOT OK
"I" hate 'php' -> OK
```

my problem is the single quotes

Comment: Possible duplicate or may be helpful:-https://stackoverflow.com/a/20767638/4248328

Comment: It is  not a duplicate of that question as this one is about skip-failing several patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *group* the alternatives you want to SKIP-FAIL and escape single quotes as you are using a single-quoted string literal:

```
'/(?:\'[^\']*\'|"[^"]*")(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\blove\b/i'
  ^^^          ^       ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9MMGE4/1).

Now, `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` will apply to both the alternatives, `\'[^\']*\'` and `"[^"]*"`.

Comment: perfect, but now I have a second problem, if the total string is contained within single or double quotes, like for example:`code'$text = <<<DATA
"I love php
"I love php"
'I love php'
"I" love 'php'"
DATA;`code`

Comment: @Robert What match(es) do you expect here?

Comment: I expect that the quotes (double or single here too), which contain the initial string are not considered and therefore the result is the same.if possible...

Comment: @Robert It is not 100% fail safe but try `(?:^["']|["']$|\'[^\']*\'|"[^"]*")(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\blove\b`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/9MMGE4/3). Note that the initial `^["']` and `["']$` do not check for the corresponding end/start quote.

Comment: from the first tests it seems to work, what problems do you think it could give, in which cases it might not be 100% fail safe

Comment: @Robert  explained in my above comment.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative, you may also a capture group to capture single or double quote and a back-reference to match the same quote:

```
$re = '/([\'"]).*?\1(*SKIP)(*F)|\blove\b/';
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/A3FPbv/1)

**PHP Code:**

```
$re = '/([\'"]).*?\1(*SKIP)(*F)|\blove\b/';
$text = preg_replace($re, 'hate', $text);
```

[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/JcAntu)